# Setting SelectedValue Binding inside FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

First of all sorry about my english.
I'm having a problem and I can't figured out how to solve it. I have a list (finalList) with DataGrid objects. I'm creating dynamically columns and rows inside a DataGrid. I have a List> where I generate the rows. My problem is that when I create a FrameworkElement typeof(TextBox) the binding works great. But when I create the frameelement with combobox, I can see the options but I can't set a SelectedValueBinding. So the combobox shows the options, but never start with a selected.

This is how I create columns dynamically

```
FrameworkElementFactory frameElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox)); 
itemsSourceBinding.Source = finalList;
frameElementFactory.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsSourceBinding);
```

This is my XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UC_CopyReferenceGrid" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"  Margin="10,10,246,10"></DataGrid>
```

I need to add the binding to the FrameworkElementFactory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `ItemsSource` binding functioning correctly?  If so, the process is more or less identical for binding `SelectedValue`:

```
frameElementFactory.SetBinding(
    Selector.SelectedValueProperty,
    new Binding {
        Path = new PropertyPath(ContentControl.ContentProperty), // ?
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    }
);
```

I'm not positive about the binding path; it should be the same as for your other columns.

Typically, one uses `SelectedValue` when the logical value is a sub-property of items in the `ItemsSource`, in which case you may need to also use the `SelectedValuePath` property to specify that property path.  Otherwise, you can simply use `SelectedItem`.

Comment: In my case the ItemSource of the Datagrid is a List<List<GridObject>> . And the source of the combobox is a List<GridObject>. When I create a TextBox the binding works perfect.  

`frameElementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));               frameElementFactory.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].Value", columnNumber)));`

Comment: If you use that property path in the code from my answer, what happens?

Comment: It didn't work. I did this:  
`frameElementFactory.SetBinding(
                    Selector.SelectedValueProperty,
                    new Binding
                    {
                        Path = new PropertyPath(string.Format("[{0}]", columnNumber)), // ?
                        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                    }
                );`

Comment: Yes!! I was having another problem, but that binding save my life. It works!! Thanks a lot...